# How to change default precision value to 2 digits instead of 3 digits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have text fields for taking amount like 12345.67890. Instead of showing all 5 digits after dot (67890) I would like to show 67 only.

To do this in the text_field if I mention :precision => 2  then it is working perfectly.

But if I have 100 text fields I don't want to place every where. I'm looking for a DRY method.  What advice do you have?

Answer (score 1):

DRY it up, extract to a helper method!

```
# helper class
class SomeHelper
  def text_field_precision_2 f, name
    f.text_field name, :precision => 2
  end
end

# view
<%= text_field_precision_2 f, :price %>
```